# Why won't this localScroll-navigation work on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, scroll

I've designed [joao.pt](http://joao.pt) to use [localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.pt/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) for vertical anchor navigation within the same page (hit the *Journal*, *Recently*, or *Contact* buttons on the top left corner of the page to try it out). Although it works on pretty much all browsers and devices, it doesn't work on Chrome—and not only doesn't it work when hitting the anchor links I mentioned above, it also doesn't load the proper section on page load. Here's the code I'm using (from the pre-minified [scripts.js](http://joao.pt/wp-content/themes/joaoramos/js/scripts.js)):

```
$.localScroll.hash({ // scroll to section on page load
    hash: true
});

$.localScroll({ // scroll when hitting anchor links
    hash: true
});
```

Comment: create a www.jsfiddle.net so people can help you

Comment: Is there anything I could do in the live website instead to make it easier for people to help me out? I'm afraid there are lots of variables (e.g. site-wide CSS and JavaScript) that could make the difference when debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just randomly fixed this issue, by literally updating the localScroll and scrollTo libraries. It wasn't really an update, since it's been 3 years since they were last updated, but well.. it's fixed.